# Given key\value pairs, find all rules that satisfy and return true

Tags: .net, rules, data-analysis

Here is an interesting problem I've been brainstorming today.

Given an object with key/value pairs and a system/tool with defined rules/queries, find all rules that return true.

For example given a person:

```
{
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "Age": 28,
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Location": "USA"
}
```

And given some rules:

```
Rule 1: Location = USA AND (Gender = Male OR Age < 20)
Rule 2: Location != USA AND (Gender = Female OR Age > 25)
```

I'd expect the system to return all the rules that would be true given the object. Then based on the rule that was true, do a specific action.

That's a simple example. The fun bits:

- The passed object can have any number of different key\value pairs
- There could be hundreds or thousands of different rules that need to be executed
- Rules can contain any combination of the key value pairs
- Performance and usability are the key
- Usable in a .Net application

The idea for a custom implementation is:

Do map reduce and only return the rules that contain the keys from the object. This would reduce the number of rules that need to be executed, but could still be a few hundred rules.

Take each rule and execute it with the given values to see if it returns true.

---

Is there a better way to do this?
Is there any tool (hopefully open source) that would already accomplish this?

The searches did not return much, and I could not even think of a proper search to do.

---

## EDIT

After some more searching online, it turns out this is solvable using [Rete Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) and numerous implementation in .Net and Java world.

This is the path I am currently headed down. If anyone has any better suggestions please provide them.

Comment: Given an object do you want a list of rules that are true for that object? Or given some rules get all the objects that satisfy those rules?

Comment: Intesting Problem - Windows Workflow Foundation contains an inferential rules engine (System.Workflow.Activities.Rules) - but it does not have the intelligence to map reduce the rules. Good luck.

Comment: Given the object, returns all rules that are true for that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why a separate step to map

Just abort the test ASAP

```
private bool? ruleMe (person p, rule r) 
{
    foreach (string rKey in r.ExtractKeys())
       if(!p.ContainsKey(rKey)) return (bool?)null;
    // process r 

}
```

or extend both to create a HaskSet of Key

```
public class person 
{
    private HashSet<String> hSkey;
    public HashSet<String> HSkey 
    {
        if (hSkey == null)
        { 
           hSkey = new HashSet<String>();
           // populate hSkey
        }
        return hSkey;
    }
}

private bool? ruleMe (person p, rule r) 
{
    if(!r.HSkey.IsProperSubset(p.HSkey))  // O(n of r.HSKey) 
       return (bool?)null;
    // process r 
}
```

Comment: My concern going down this path is performance. Given an object with a hundred properties and a few thousand rules.

Comment: Have you tired this?  What would be faster than IsProperSubset?

Comment: Really your concern is performance.  I just tested with 1,000 objects 100 properties each and 10,0000 rules 100 properties each the TOTAL time on a P4 is 4 seconds.   4 seconds is a performance concern?  What are you looking for?

Comment: That is actually pretty good! No did not have a chance to test, we are still in early decision making on direction, but it was in the list of things to test when the time comes. I am grateful for the test you did! Performance hit was an assumption.

Comment: Pretty good?  What are are you looking for?  That is 4 milliseconds per object.